# Generators of the fundamental groups of the 8-figure and the torus

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I have two doubts strictly related to each other.

1) Firstly, consider the $8$-figure, namely the union of two circles in a point $x_1$. Using the Seifert-Van Kampen's theorem I proved that its fundamental group is the free group on two generators. Now say $a$ the closed path in $x_0$ around only the left circle and say $b$ the closed path in $x_0$ around only the right circle. How can I prove that the classes of $a$ and $b$ are different and that they generate the fundamental group?

2) Secondly, I want to prove that the fundamental group of the torus is $\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z$ using the Seifert-Van Kampen's theorem. Consider the torus as the square with identified opposite edges. Say $U=T-\{y\}$ where $y$ is a point inside the square and say $x_1$ is the vertex of the identified square. Now it's ok for me that $U$ is a retract of the $8$-figure and so we know that $\pi_1(U,x_1)$ is equal to the free group on two generators. My problem is that even if I assume my point 1) I don't understand why: "classes of $a$ and $b$ generate the fundamental group of $8$-figure implies they generate $\pi_1(U,x_1)$ too". Of course now $a$ is the closed path in $x_1$ on the horizontal edge and $b$ is the closed path in $x_1$ on the vertical edge.

From this point I know how to complete the exercise.

Comment: 1) This is basically what the Seifert vanKampen theorem says.
2) $\pi_1(A\times B)=\pi_1(A)\times\pi_1(B)$ holds for path connected (or pointed) spaces and easy. What product is the torus?

Comment: 1) I can't see this as obvious 2) I know the formula and that $T=S^1\times S^1$ but I wanted to use the S. VK theorem as I stated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Seifert-Van Kampen theorem does not just give you the abstract fact that the figure 8 has fundamental group $\mathbb{Z} * \mathbb{Z}$. It gives you an actual formula for an isomorphism. So, look carefully at the proof you say you have, look carefully at the formula for the isomorphism given by the Seifert-Van Kampen theorem, write down the isomorphism that the theorem gives you for this particular problem, and look at the images in $\mathbb{Z} * \mathbb{Z}$ of $a$ and $b$ under that isomorphism. The formula for the isomorphism should show you that $a$ maps to a generator of the first $\mathbb{Z}$ and $b$ to a generator of the second $\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{Z} * \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Problem 1). Say $X=$figure $8$, $U=$right circle $+$ (left circle minus a point different from $x_1$), and similarly $V=$left circle$+$(right circle minus a point different from $x_1$). Now we have the inclusions: $i_1:U\to X$ and $i_2:V\to X$. These induce $\phi: U*V\to X$ defined by  $g_1g_2\mapsto i_1(g_1)i_2(g_2)$ that can be extended to the homomorphism $f:\pi_1(U)*\pi_1(V)\to \pi_1(X)$ In this particular case the Theorem says that $f$ is surjective.Now note that $U$ is a retract of the only right circle and so its fundamental group is $\mathbb Z$.But now I have my problem:

Comment: We know that the generator of the right circle is the class of the closed path around $x_1$. Call it the class of $a$. How can I deduce that the class of $a$ is also the generator of the retraction of the circle, namely $U$? This seems a property of the functions of retraction and not of the isomorphism of Van Kampen. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: You're on the right track, but you must use the induced homomorphism of the retraction $U \to a$. You haven't drawn out all the conclusions that you need to regarding the behavior of this induced homomorphism.

Comment: First, to be clear, the retraction maps $U$ to $a$, not the other way around. Second, the retraction $r_1 : U \to a$ is more than just an ordinary retraction, it is a deformation retraction. Like any deformation retraction, the map $r_1$ is a homotopy equivalence, its homotopy inverse is the inclusion map $i_1 : a \to U$, and those two maps induce inverse isomorphisms $(r_1)_* : \pi_1(U,p) \to \pi_1(a,p)$ and $(i_1)_* : \pi_1(a,p) \to \pi_1(U,p)$ (where $p$ is the crossing point of the figure 8).

Comment: Since $i_1$ is the inclusion map, it follows that the isomorphism $(i_1)_* : \pi_1(a,p) \to \pi_1(U,p)$ takes the class of the loop $a$ in $\pi_1(a,p)$, which I'll denote as $[a]_a$, to the class of the loop $a$ in $\pi_1(U,p)$, which I'll denote as $[a]_U$. Since $[a]_a$ is a generator of the infinite cyclic group $\pi_1(a,p)$, it follows that $[a]_U$ is a generator of the cyclic group $\pi_1(U,p)$.

Comment: Firstly: thank you very much, this is the formalism that I was looking for. So the key point is about the property of the deformation retractions rather than Van Kampen. Only a thing about your notation: to be more rigorous when you define $r_1$ you should put a space instead of $a$ right? I mean since we call $a$ the loop around the right circle we should call for example $R$ the right circle as space and so write $r_1:U\to R$. This note is just to be sure that I have understood everything.Secondly: problem 2) Say

Comment: $X=$torus (thought as the identified square), $U=$torus$-$the central point of the square and $V=$torus$-$(horizontal edge+vertical edge). My question is about $U$. We have a deformation retraction $r_2:U\to$ (figure 8) that is a homotopy equivalence, its homotopy inverse is the inclusion map $i_2:$(figure 8)$\to U$ and these maps induce inverse isomorphisms $(r_2)*:\pi_1(U,x_1)\to \pi1$(figure 8,$x_1)$ and  $(i_2)*:\pi_1$(figure 8,x_1)$\to \pi_1(U,x_1)$ where $x_1$ is the vertex of the identified square.

Comment: The deformation retraction acts in this way:push the interior of the identified square to the horizontal and vertical edge.The figure that you obtain is not exactly the figure 8 but is homeomorphic to it thanks to a map $g$ (like the identified square is not the tours as donut but is homeomorphic to it).In particular under $g$ the horizontal edge become the right circle and the vertical edge become the left circle. So if you call $a$ the horizontal loop in and $b$ the vertical loop in you have thanks to $g$ that they generate the fundamental group of the identified square without interior. Now

Comment: thanks to the fact that $i_2$ is the inclusion map, (i_2)* maps $[a]_8$ to $[a]_U$ and $[b]_8$ to $[b]_U$ and similarly as done before since the first couple generate the fundamental group of the figure 8 and $(i_2)*$ is an isomorphism, the second couple generate the fundamental group of $U$. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, that all sounds correct. And yes, I was abusing notation, using the symbol $a$ (and similarly $b$) to stand both for one of the two circles in the figure 8 and for the closed path that goes once around that circle.

Comment: ok so give me some time to rethink and rewrite on a paper these ideas. If there are no problems I'll mark your answer. I really appreciated your help since algebraic topology is very beautiful but sometimes the texts about it take for granted some steps of the proofs because they just refer to the intuitive ideas. For example, if you take Massey's book there aren't written these steps when he calculates the fundamental group of the torus. He just claims these things and he substitutes a formal proof with pictures. Sometimes I don't feel comfortable to trust every picture.I hope this is normal.

Comment: It is normal, although it is also important to learn to learn the intuition and to learn the notation well enough that in the end you are able to trust that the notational steps to writing things are essentially mechanical. You might also try a variety of algebraic topology books; Munkres is generally more careful about notational matters.

Comment: 2)When you consider a collection of groups $G_λ$ in order to define the free product you have to suppose that $G_i\cap G_j=\emptyset$ if $i\not=j$ right?I know that you can suppose to be every time in this circumstance without loss of generality (replacing the groups by isomorphic copies if necessary) but I mean, isn't writing $\mathbb Z*\mathbb Z$ an abuse of notation?Consider 22: this cannot be in reduced form since every 2 is in the same group but at the same time I could say that for me the first 2 is of the first factor and that the second 2 is of the second factor.(does it make sense?)

Comment: How can we solve this notation problem? It seems to me that many texts (Massey for example) never take care of it and they never consider the case where two groups of the collection are equal. Except these things the other comments work for me and so I'll mark your answer after the end of this last discussion. thank you very much

Comment: 1) How can we prove that $[a]_U$ and $[b]_V$ are two different objects? Only because they are sets of maps with different codomain? It doesn't seem enough to me because if I consider the classes $[a]_U$ and $[a]_8$ I wouldn't answer that they are different (even if they really have different codomain, they have same image). How can I solve it ? thank you very much. Note: I wrote firstly 2) because before that there was a wrong comment that I deleted

Comment: There's a lot of set theory behind your latest questions, so I'll just keep my comments brief. To work around the abuse of notation in $\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}$, proceed in a similar fashion to the abuse of notation in a disjoint union https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_union. $[a]_U$ is an element of $\pi_1(U,p)$ and $[b]_U$ is an element of $\pi_1(V,p)$, and since $U$ and $V$ are different sets, these groups are disjoint.

Comment: ok but the groups are disjoint because every element in $\pi_1(U,p)$ is a particular class in which every element is of the form $\alpha: I\to U$ and every element in $\pi_1(V,p)$ is a particular class in which every element is of the form $\beta: I\to V$, right? I mean, different codomains of the loops implies disjoint groups? thank you for your patience

Comment: That looks correct.

Comment: If you could take a look on this question I really would appreciate it. It's related to something that we have discussed http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1835294/on-the-definition-of-free-products